# pyautogui / pyscreeze can't find pillow even though it is successfully installed into the same package folder and I can import it

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-imaging-library, pyautogui

I'm following a course called Automate the Boring Stuff, and I'm on the last part about pyautogui and pillow. I can import pyautogui and pillow successfully and I can use the keystroke functions of pyautogui but if I try to run a function in pyautogui that involves pillow it gives me this error. The function I'm trying to run is `pyautogui.screenshot()`

```
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\offic\PycharmProjects\test\venv\Lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 134, in wrapper
    raise PyScreezeException('The Pillow package is required to use this function.')
pyscreeze.PyScreezeException: The Pillow package is required to use this function.
```

and here is the code in pyscreeze that determines if pillow is there

```
try:
    from PIL import Image
    from PIL import ImageOps
    from PIL import ImageDraw
    if sys.platform == 'win32': # TODO - Pillow now supports ImageGrab on macOS.
        from PIL import ImageGrab
    _PILLOW_UNAVAILABLE = False
except ImportError:
    # We ignore this because failures due to Pillow not being installed
    # should only happen when the functions that specifically depend on
    # Pillow are called. The main use case is when PyAutoGUI imports
    # PyScreeze, but Pillow isn't installed because the user is running
    # some platform/version of Python that Pillow doesn't support, then
    # importing PyAutoGUI should not automatically fail because it
    # imports PyScreeze.
    # So we have a `pass` statement here since a failure to import
    # Pillow shouldn't crash PyScreeze.
    _PILLOW_UNAVAILABLE = True
```

```
def requiresPillow(wrappedFunction):
    """
    A decorator that marks a function as requiring Pillow to be installed.
    This raises PyScreezeException if Pillow wasn't imported.
    """
    @functools.wraps(wrappedFunction)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if _PILLOW_UNAVAILABLE:
            raise PyScreezeException('The Pillow package is required to use this function.')
        return wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

if I try to just type 'from PIL import Image' it gives this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Edu 2019.1\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\offic\PycharmProjects\test\venv\Lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 93, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (C:\Users\offic\PycharmProjects\test\venv\Lib\site-packages\PIL\__init__.py)
```

and this is when I installed Pillow

```
C:\Users\offic>py -m pip install --user Pillow
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\users\offic\pycharmprojects\test\venv\lib\site-packages (7.1.1)
```

[image: this is what pillow looks like in my package directory]
this is what pillow looks like in my package directory

and pyscreeze says it's supposedly satisfied with the install of Pillow

```
C:\Users\offic>py -m pip install --user pyscreeze
Requirement already satisfied: pyscreeze in c:\users\offic\pycharmprojects\test\venv\lib\site-packages (0.1.26)
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow>=5.2.0 in c:\users\offic\pycharmprojects\test\venv\lib\site-packages (from pyscreeze) (7.1.1)
```

I don't know what is going on because I've had almost no problems with installing packages before and it seems to be in the right location and up to date. Please help me!

Answer (score 3):

Even I had the same error, here is what worked for me:

> ```
> python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
> python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow
> ```

I found this in the official documentation of Pillow package

Comment: This worked for me today on a windows machine in an anaconda virtual environment

Answer (score 1):

I'm using windows and this method worked for me.

pip install --upgrade pip

pip install --upgrade Pillow

Answer (score 0):

Despite the misleading contextual evidence, what you are looking for is the *cv2* library, not *PIL* strictly.

So install *cv2*, e.g. using pip:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Then import it within your Python script:

```py
import cv2
```

Then run it.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue,  I have the latest version of the python interpreter, the latest version of the pyscreeze, I read the docs, but nothing found, I google it, but hopelessly nothing,
But I was about losing hope when I found this, we can call the `pyscreeze` module instead of the `pyautogui` module,

```
import pyautogui
import pyscreeze
image = pyscreeze.screenshot('screenshot.png')
print(image.size)
```

Finding more at https://pypi.org/project/PyScreeze/

Answer (score -1):

For my case, in pycharm,

move these two files:

PIL,

Pillow-9.4.0.dist-info,

from

C:\Users\xxxxxxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages

to PyCharm project

C:\Users\xxxxxxxxxxxx\PycharmProjects\xxxxxxxxxxxx\venv\Lib\site-packages

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9wOb.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: in general, while this may work, I'd suggest installing the files directly using the `pip` of the virtualenv in question (in this case, through pycharm python-packages GUI). This will be more reliable if the venv is a different python version or etc.

Answer (score -2):

It's a version issue, you can solve it by

- uninstalling current *Pillow* version
- and re-installing the proper version, e.g. `8.1.2`

```
pip uninstall Pillow, 
pip install Pillow==8.1.2
```

(call me "LEI, FENG")